# Reading date, time and data in csv file in fortran

Tags: fortran

I am trying to read a dataset which looks like this

```
DATE,TIME,val
1/1/2001,1:00:00,0
```

with the program

```
program main
implicit none

real :: val
character(len=8) :: date
character(len=7) :: time
open(1,file='data.csv',status='old')
read(1,*) ! header
read(1,fmt=100)date,time,val
100 FORMAT (A,1x,A,1x,F3.1)
end program
```

This is all fine if the date and time always have 8 or 7 characters but they don't e.g.

```
 4/21/2001,19:00:00,0
```

How should I declare the format for fortran to read both the date,time,val lines in the example?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could read all the entire `data, time, value` line into a single string and then process that to extract the individual elements, something along the lines of

```
program main
implicit none

real :: val
character(len=10) :: date
character(len=8) :: time

character(len=100) :: line
integer :: n1, n2, end

open(1, file='data.csv', status='old')

! Read entire second line into `line`, ignoring the header
read(1,*) ! header
read(1,'(A100)') line

! Determine locations of the first and last comma in `line` and the
! end of the line:
n1  = index(line, ',')
n2  = index(line, ',', back=.True.)
end = len_trim(data)

! Split line up according to position of commas and assign to 
! appropriate variables
date = data(1:n1-1)
time = data(n1+1:n2-1)
read(data(n2+1:end), *) val ! Internal read, for converting from string to float

end program main
```

Note that this is highly specialised to the example data in the question, but it shouldn't be too hard to generalise this code.

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined the "data" variable you're using. The other problem with this solution, is now you are stuck with all of your variables as characters, which may not be useful for analysis.

Comment: Though this would fit better as a comment, since it doesn't _fully_ answer the question, I realize that you have too few points to actually comment. Hopefully soon! To learn more about this site, view the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Also, for how to answer a question, please refer to [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).